# потеряется ли память при thread.Abort()?

Tags: c#, многопоточность, memory

запускаю поток, в нем открывается форма с помощью Application.Run(frm)

через некоторое время основной поток завершает его с помощью thread.Abort()
проблема в том, что иногда (редко, но все же) возникает

> System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: Thread was being aborted.

стэктрэйсы разные, но они все содержат события прорисовки контролов, по-видимому, этой формы.
если я перехвачу событие этого дополнительного потока

```
Application.ThreadException += (s, e) => { };
```

т.е. просто заглушу его ошибки (в нем нет ничего критичного, это информационное окно), не останутся ли ссылки внутри этого потока и не останется ли он в памяти?

в качестве примера можно рассмотреть такой код:

```
    void runThread()
    {
        //запускаем поток
        var t = new Thread(showForm);
        t.Start();
        //что-то делаем
        Thread.Sleep(10000);
        // грубо завершаем дочерний поток
        t.Abort();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// ф-ция дочернего потока
    /// </summary>
    void showForm()
    {
        Application.ThreadException += (s, e) => { }; // достаточно ли этого чтобы тихо закрыть поток?
        Application.Run(new myForm()); // на этой форме может происходить что угодно в плане отображения. 
        // данными не оперируем, только визульные фишечки. допустим, гифка крутится
    }
```

Comment: покажите код где приходит  `thread.Abort() `

Comment: Вы [не должны использовать](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1560567/276994) `Thread.Abort()` </discussion>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Никаких лишних ссылок не останется, сборщик мусора все приберет. Если только вы сами не наоткрываете неуправляемых ресурсов.

---

Тем не менее, я бы не рекомендовал решать эту задачу через Thread.Abort. Правильнее останавливать дополнительный UI-поток через Application.ExitThread или закрывая главную форму.

К сожалению, оба действия можно делать только в том потоке, где эта форма была создана. Для того, чтобы передать сигнал на закрытие в другой поток, проще всего 
использовать токен отмены ([CancellationToken](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.threading.cancellationtoken(v=vs.110).aspx), .NET 4.0+) и контекст синхронизации ([SynchronizationContext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext(v=vs.110).aspx)).

Получается примерно так:

```
void RunThread() {
    var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    var t = new Thread(ShowForm);
    t.Start(cts.Token);
    //что-то делаем
    Thread.Sleep(10000);
    // аккуратно завершаем дочерний поток
    cts.Cancel();
    t.Join();
}

void ShowForm(object obj)
{
    var token = (CancellationToken)obj;
    var form = new MyForm(); // В этот момент устанавливается контекст синхронизации потока

    var ctx = SynchronizationContext.Current; // В этот момент контекст синхронизации должен быть уже установлен

    using (token.Register(() => { 
        ctx.Post(_ => Application.ExitThread(), null); // Нельзя использовать Send - в этот момент мы можем уже выходить из `Application.Run` по какой-то причине
    })) { // Нельзя использовать useSynchronizationContext - он внутри использует Send
        Application.Run(form);
    }
}
```

Comment: при использовании Вашего кода получил 'System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource' does not contain a definition for 'Register' and no extension method 'Register' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: прошу прощения, использовал token вместо token.Token

Comment: поясните, пожалуйста, эту запись: ctx.Post(_ => Application.ExitThread()

Comment: @vvsibir дополнительному потоку отправляется оконное сообщение чтобы он завершил выполнение метода `Application.Run`.